# how to add a static layout to another static layout at run time

Tags: android, runtime, addition, android-linearlayout, at-command

i am a new developer in android.i got problem with layouts in android.

i have used three layouts in main.xml as follows

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="60dip" 
android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/tabmessage" android:id="@+id/linearLayout01">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#000000" android:text="layout1">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="200dip" android:background="#ff0000" android:id="@+id/linearLayout03">
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="60dip" 
android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/tabmessage" android:id="@+id/linearLayout02">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#000000" android:text="layout2" android:id="@+id/textView2">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i have done a class as follows

MyClass.java

public class MyShout extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout layout1=((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout01));
    LinearLayout layout2=((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout02));
    LinearLayout layout3=((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout03));

  }        
}
```

here i would like to add layout1 to layout3.how can i add layout1 to layout3 at run time? please help me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
layout3.addView(layout1); 
//or
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new //setup here positioning rules
layout3.addView(layout1, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do like this.

You can do as:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout>
           </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i know this but i want do like that.if u know correct solution then give answer

Comment: Please stop adding the endings to your answers, it just adds unnecessary noise